# Substituting matched characters with a value from object

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string as follows:

```
{hours}/DP1/{facilityId}/CP23/{minutes}
```

and have an object which is:

```
{
  hours: 4,
  facilityId: "abd-rtyo-99e",
  minutes: 43
}
```

I want to get the output string as :

```
4/DP1/abd-rtyo-99e/CP23/43
```

thus replacing any token inside `{}` with a value from object. So `hours` inside `{}` gets replaced with `4` from the object, `minutes` by `43` and so on. How could I do this?

I could detect characters inside `{}` using a regular expression like `{\w+}` but don't know how to proceed with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to match word characters, and use a replacer function which checks to see if the key exists on the object - if so, return the associated value:

```js
const input = '{hours}/DP1/{facilityId}/CP23/{minutes}';
const obj = {
  hours: 4,
  facilityId: "abd-rtyo-99e",
  minutes: 43
};
const output = input.replace(
  /{(\w+)}/g,
  (match, possibleKey) => obj[possibleKey] ? obj[possibleKey] : match
);
console.log(output);
// 4/DP1/abd-rtyo-99e/CP23/43
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all the keys of object using `for..in` and then `replace()` the key in original string with the value of key

```js
let str = '{hours}/DP1/{facilityId}/CP23/{minutes}'

const obj = {
  hours: 4,
  facilityId: "abd-rtyo-99e",
  minutes: 43
}
let result = str;
for(let k in obj){
  result = result.replace(`{${k}}`,obj[k]);
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and use the key and value in the replacement:

```js
let obj = {
  hours: 4,
  facilityId: "abd-rtyo-99e",
  minutes: 43
};
let str = '{hours}/DP1/{facilityId}/CP23/{minutes}';
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  str = str.replace(`{${key}}`, value);
});

console.log(str);
```